# PHP Date Function Producing Wrong Day of Week?

Tags: php, date, datetime, wamp

When I run this on WAMP, I get "Wed" when I believe I should get "Fri".  Given that tomorrow is Friday and the 10th of October, 2014, I am reasonably confident it should be Friday. :-D

```
        $start_day = date("D","2014-10-10");
        echo $start_day;
```

I *must* be missing something obvious.  I have never had issues with the date functions before.

Thank you in advance for your kind consideration.

Comment: This also is happening on my web host, so I am more worried than ever that I am missing something obvious.

Comment: `date` doesn't take a string. It takes a timestamp.

Comment: Yes, I feel quite silly now, but I had hit a point where I was simply blind to the error.  Probably too little caffeine/sleep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter of the date function is an integer representing the number of seconds since the start of the unix epoch (1-1-1970), not some free-form date string. So, really, you're asking what day of the week was 2014 seconds after 1-1-1970.

You'll want to use stringtotime first:

```
$start_day = date("D",strtotime("2014-10-10"));
echo $start_day;
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete and kind assistance.  It's been a while since I constructed a datetime argument (about 18 months), and I was playing around with the Date::Time structures to get it from a string before I reverted to this method.

Answer (score 3):

The `timestamp` parameter [should be a Unix timestamp (integer)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), not a string:

> `timestamp`
>
> The optional timestamp parameter is an integer Unix timestamp that defaults to the current local time if a timestamp is not given. In other words, it defaults to the value of time().

You can use [`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert a string to a suitable timestamp.

Comment: Chris, I was just waiting for the time to run down. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

RTM: http://php.net/date

date() expects a TIMESTAMP as its second argument. You're passing in a random string. Since it's a string, it'll try to convert that numer-number-number to a string, and end up with just "number".

so you're really doing

```
date('D', 2010);
```

which corresponds to (roughly) Jan 1,1970 00:50:00 am

Comment: Thank you. I assure you I did read the documentation.  I am just in a bit of a haze from juggling too much at once right now and very rusty with datetime manipulations.